# I want to change zoom of google map in angular js when some location search in search box

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

At initialization

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.3753, 69.3451),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
 $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
```

At search

```
 $scope.map.zoom = 10;
```

currently I use this code but its not working, at initialization of google map zoom=6 that is working properly but when I want to change on search it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use setZoom()..

at Search Make it 
$scope.map.setZoom(10)... I Hope It works

Comment: now i want to put condition on search box to check whether its city or country

Answer (score 0):

var mapOptions = {
    zoom: level,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.3753, 69.3451),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
 $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

On Search, set level to some value.
$Scope.level = 10